# How to create virtual CD drive on Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos

How does one go about creating a virtual CD driver on Mac OS X programatically?

I can't find any relevant Cocoa APIs or any pure C BSD solutions.

Any help or information is appreciated.

Comment: @Ahruman MacFUSE project is basically dead. The owner left the project several years ago. Instead MacFUSE one should use [fuse4x](http://fuse4x.org) (fork of macfuse).

Comment: @user576557 this question was asked several years ago :-P

Comment: it just helped me - Future Man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to use the I/O Kit framework to develop your own device driver that would emulate a virtual CD drive.  Here are some links to the relevant APIs to get you started.

[I/O Kit Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html)

[I/O Kit Device Driver Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WritingDeviceDriver/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html)

[Kernel Extension Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/hello_iokit.html)

Comment: Getting 404 when opening the links

Answer (score 2):

There are several different answers people have proposed here. The issue at hand is what are you trying to accomplish. If you really want to emulate a CD ROM (down to the commandset) you will need to write a device driver. If your goal is merely to emulate a block device with contents similiar to a CD you can create a disk image using disk utility and let the builtin disk image driver handle it for you.

MacFUSE is useful if you want to present some sort of custom filesystem functionality, but if what you are looking for is something that has the same semantics as an optical disc (whether that is and block or command set level) it is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply looking to mount an ISO or something then it's done through the Disk Utility, simply drag it into the side-bar and then select it and choose mount.

If you want to do it from code you can issue the hdiutil command, as shown [here](http://osxdaily.com/2008/04/22/easily-mount-an-iso-in-mac-os-x/). I'm not sure if there's an API call to do it, but getting that command to do the work is quite painless.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to mount a custom volume is [MacFUSE](http://macfuse.googlecode.com/). It handles the IOKit details for you and lets you write the implementation in user space. However, I don’t think you can make a MacFUSE “look like” a CD; you’d have to modify FUSE to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nosey around [DAEMON Tools for Mac](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/home)'s driver:

`/Library/Extensions/DAEMONToolsVirtualSCSIBus.kext/Contents/MacOS/DAEMONToolsVirtualSCSIBus`

I disassembled the binary using [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com) and discovered they are using
[IOSCSIProtocolServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/ioscsiprotocolservices?changes=latest_major).

[image]